# How i could access to the information inside the HTML

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest, python-3.x

Hello i had a project what send information using the POST method to make a request in a server app write in Python, i want to know if after i make the request i can have full access to the elements in the page?

Comment: Do you want to know about the XML part, or the HTTP POST part?

Comment: Sorry i make the wrong question let me re-formulated

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear.

The most popular libraries for parsing XML and HTML in Python are:

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) - older, but still popular

[lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) - The defacto standard if you can access libxml wherever you're running your code

Using these libraries, you should be able to extract whatever you need and return it to the client.

Comment: I want to know if i can extract the information of another element inside the page when the client makes click into a submit in the form.

Comment: That sounds like a javascript problem. Perhaps you shouldn't have tagged it as Python then?

Comment: It's a python issue because when i've make the request only the server knows what elements i need to extract the information, but i want to know if i am limited to the form or i can have access to any element?

Comment: In order for this question to be answered, you need to post far more detail about what you are doing, what you want to happen, and how you have already tried to implement it.